# How to perform computation on a temporary table using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the average of a column after doing a division grouped by weeks.

Here is my original table

| id | week | amount | div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 50 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 40 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 35 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 60 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 70 | 9 |

First I want to SUM them with group by weeks, and divide the amount/div

| week | amount | div | amount/div |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 90 | 8 | 11.25 |
| 4 | 95 | 13 | 7.30 |
| 6 | 70 | 9 | 7.77 |

Now to get the average of amount/div which is `(11.25+7.3+7.77)/3 = 8.77`

I just want to get the `8.77`

Here is what I tried:

```sql
SELECT AVG(amount/ div) from mytable GROUP BY week
```

but I didn't get the desired result of `8.77`

Comment: Why do you think a table being temporary makes any difference to the query

Comment: I don't want a temporary table. If it is possible without one then I am very much happy.

Comment: I am getting this error ```#1111 - Invalid use of group function``` query ```SELECT SUM(AVG(amount/ divider)) / COUNT(week) FROM test```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample DB made.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c7fa7/9

Used `FLOOR` to match your values 11.25, 7.3, 7.77, usual ROUND(...,2) got 1 cent difference.

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  week INT,
  amount INT,
  divs INT
);

INSERT INTO stats ( week, amount, divs ) VALUES ( 5, 50, 5 );
INSERT INTO stats ( week, amount, divs ) VALUES ( 5, 40, 3 );
INSERT INTO stats ( week, amount, divs ) VALUES ( 4, 35, 3 );
INSERT INTO stats ( week, amount, divs ) VALUES ( 4, 60, 10 );
INSERT INTO stats ( week, amount, divs ) VALUES ( 6, 70, 9 );

SELECT ROUND(AVG(amount_divs), 2)
FROM (
  SELECT FLOOR(100* SUM(amount)/SUM(divs))/100 AS amount_divs
  FROM stats 
  GROUP BY week
) x
```

If you run following query

```
SELECT AVG(amount/divs)
FROM stats
```

It has different meaning, it is the average of all records (5 values), not the 3 after `SUM`

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for